# Compass: Failed to run compass on 'C:/wamp/www/[...]/public/config.rb'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, phpstorm, compass-sass

I got this error since few hours and i can not fix it...
Could you help me please??
[here an exhaustive img of my parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuiWC.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using sass.bat in both Compass settings and file watcher. But it should be compass (`C:\Ruby193\bin\compass.bat`, for example), not sass. Did you install Compass?

Comment: Hello thaks to helping me,

I installed ruby 2.3, there is no compass.bat in Ruby/bin, only scss.bat, sass.bat and other files called scss-convret, I tryed all, i dont know what to do

Comment: and yes, I installed gem for sass and scss

Comment: You need installing Compass (http://compass-style.org/install/) to run it, it doesn't come with Ruby, and is not installed when installing sass/scss

Comment: **I had to  write "compass create" in the terminal of my IDE** (PHPStorm), thank you guys that solve