# Configuring PhpStorm for using Susy in Drupal 8 project

Tags: phpstorm, drupal-8, susy

I need help to configuring PhpStorm for using Susy in Drupal 8 project. My actions:

1. Install Ruby
2. Install Compass (cmd => `gem install compass`)
3. Install Susy (cmd => `gem install susy`)
4. Change directory to core theme in cmd
5. Run in cmd => `compass config`
6. Add in config.rb line => `require "susy"`
7. Run in cmd => `compass create . -r susy -u susy`
8. Add watcher SCSS

Result error:

```
cmd.exe /D /C call C:/Ruby23/bin/scss.bat --no-cache --update main.scss:main.css
error _grids.scss (Line 4: File to import not found or unreadable: susy.)
```

Where did I make a mistake? Please, help, can't find answer 2 days.

Comment: 1) Please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37166051/783119 2) If still nothing -- since you are using compass ... should not you use compass for compiling as well? http://stackoverflow.com/a/37166495/783119